# How I can Change String Value from another class?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

```
public class Class1
{
    public string word;
    public string GetString()
    {
       ....
    }

}




public class Class2 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Class1[] class1;



    void Start()
    {
        class1 = new Class1[3];
        getText();
    }




    void getText()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
        {
            class1[i].word = "new Text";
            class1[i].GetString();

        }
    }
}
```

How I can Change (word) from **Class2** ?

I get this **error:** `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you've initialized the `class1` array, all its elements are `null`s, and you'd need to individually initialize each them before attempting to access their members.

```cs
void getText()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
    {
        class1[i] = new Class1(); // Here!
        class1[i].word = "new Text";
        class1[i].GetString();

    }
}
```